# Iterate through matrix dynamically with filter

Tags: vba, excel, matrix, filter

I have a matrix with lots of rows which do have different row lengths. As you can see in the image below, row 3 ends at column T, whereas row 8 ends at column L. What I am trying to do is to loop through every row of the matrix with the fleet name "Taxi" and sum up every entry.

[image]

How can I accomplish this? The main problem I face is with iterating through the rows and finding the end of the row dynamically and how to filter the table beforehand by the fleetname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code does what you want

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim LastRow as Long
Dim i as Long 
Dim dblSum as Double 'your sum

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

With sht
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i=2 to LastRow
        If .Cells(i,1).Value = "Taxi" Then
           LastColumn = .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
           dblSum = Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, LastColumn)))
        End if
    Next i
End with

Set sht = Nothing
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! May I ask you two questions. I do not quite understand the line where you Sum up the entries of the row. You wrote: dblSum = Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(i,1), .Cells(i, LastColumn))). Why is the second parameter of the first Cells-call a 1? And second: I have already tried out your code, but I am getting an error at line Set sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveWorkbook. It says runtime error 438. Object does not support this method. Maybe you know the solution for this problem? Thank you again for your help :)

Comment: First it should be 2 - we start sum from second column.
Second it should be ActiveSheet